# UIPickerView slot machine effect by slowing down and staggering the spinner animation

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'd like to slow down the animation speed of the pickerview to simulate a slot machine effect.

How do I slow the animation speed of

```
[pickerView selectRow:601 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Also, how can I stagger the animations so that component 1 animates after component 0 animates, etc.. just like a slot machine.

I've tried the following code to stagger the spins and they all seem to spin at the same time.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"reel1" context:nil]; // nil = dummy
    [UIPickerView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIPickerView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(reelAnimationFinished:finished:context:)];
    [reel selectRow:24 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

- (void) reelAnimationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context {
    if (animationID == @"reel1")
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"reel2" context:nil]; // nil = dummy
        [UIPickerView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIPickerView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(reelAnimationFinished:finished:context:)];
        [reel selectRow:26 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else if (animationID == @"reel2")
    {
        [reel selectRow:29 inComponent:2 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: and this is assuming the user is starting the picker view at row 0, right?

Comment: sure, or row 5 so that they don't see blank rows on top

Comment: Did you solve this issue?